# how can i run the output of stdout in bash on ubuntu

Tags: shell, stdout

for instance if I wanted to use echo `'clear' | $_` or `echo 'import subprocess;subprocess.call('clear',shell=True);'| python -c $_` is this possible on ubuntu or linux terminal to take the stdout and run it I believe I am misusing the `$_` as this just runs the previous command

for instance I have a python command that is Base64 Encoded `cHJpbnQoImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIik=` that decodes as `print("hello World")` through command line I have tried `echo 'cHJpbnQoImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIik=' | base64 -d | python -c $_` and get a Trace back `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'self' is not defined` how can I get this to run the results of stdout or use it in a one liner as a variable. I realize this is a weird question Im just trying to learn how the information on stdout can be used or accessed. Thank you for your time and input it is greatly appreciated.

Update still no luck I have also tried `echo 'cHJpbnQoImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIik=' | base64 -d >$1| python -c $1` and revieve `Error: ambiguous redirect >$1`

Comment: The result does show the base64 decoded messsage but does not run it

Comment: Have you tried `echo ... | base64 -d | python -`